# Split a column of serial number into multiple different columns using Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

For example a table contain product names, serial numbers, and product descriptions.

One of the serial numbers is the following: 12A-BCD3456-7899.

How do you separate this serial number into 6 different columns of 12, A, BCD, 34, 56, and 7899 by using Python Pandas given that  the amount and order of letters and numbers are consistent? e.g. first 2 of the serial number are always numbers (12), then a single letter(A), followed by "-", then 3 letters (BCD), 4 numbers(3456), "-", and closed by 4 numbers (7899).

The multiple columns should be added in between the product name and the product description or at the end of the table without messing up the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['A'] = df['serial_nmber'].str[0:2]
df['B'] = df['serial_nmber'].str[2]
df['C'] = df['serial_nmber'].str[4:7]
df['D'] = df['serial_nmber'].str[7:9]
df['E'] = df['serial_nmber'].str[9:11]
df['F'] = df['serial_nmber'].str[12:16]
```

Comment: does this works for different serial number of every row?

Comment: Yes it works for all serial numbers with the same format as specified

Comment: When I put that into the code it gives me a warning although it works: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
import pandas as pd
    
# creating dataframe with copy value for demo purpose
df = pd.DataFrame({'serial':['12A-BCD3456-7899']*10}) 

def processing(row):
  '''adding '-' to the serial value to make easy the split of string'''
  s='-'.join([row.serial[:2],row.serial[2:7], row.serial[7:9],row.serial[9:]])
  return s

# process the 'serial' value, split and create new column
ndf = df.apply(processing,axis=1).str.split('-', expand=True)

ndf['serial']=df['serial'] # add the 'serial' column to the new dataframe
ndf
```

**Output**: before processing

```
    serial
0   12A-BCD3456-7899
1   12A-BCD3456-7899
2   12A-BCD3456-7899
3   12A-BCD3456-7899
4   12A-BCD3456-7899
5   12A-BCD3456-7899
6   12A-BCD3456-7899
7   12A-BCD3456-7899
8   12A-BCD3456-7899
9   12A-BCD3456-7899
```

**Output**: after processing

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5       serial
0   12  A   BCD 34  56  7899    12A-BCD3456-7899
1   12  A   BCD 34  56  7899    12A-BCD3456-7899
2   12  A   BCD 34  56  7899    12A-BCD3456-7899
3   12  A   BCD 34  56  7899    12A-BCD3456-7899
4   12  A   BCD 34  56  7899    12A-BCD3456-7899
5   12  A   BCD 34  56  7899    12A-BCD3456-7899
6   12  A   BCD 34  56  7899    12A-BCD3456-7899
7   12  A   BCD 34  56  7899    12A-BCD3456-7899
8   12  A   BCD 34  56  7899    12A-BCD3456-7899
9   12  A   BCD 34  56  7899    12A-BCD3456-7899
```